# Why are faces on same plane different shades of grey in solid viewport view (not normal issue)?

Tags: 3d-view, faces

In object mode with solid viewport shading, some of the faces here are clearly a different shade of grey despite all being on the same plane:

[image: different shades of grey]

There's no material associated with the object and anyway as it's the solid viewport view, materials don't come into play.
It's not a normals issue:

[image: normals]

With face orientation turned on everything looks as expected (all blue on one side and all red on the other).

[image: face orientation]

I've popped out the sidebar and looked at each of the faces, in turn, to see if any had odd vertex or edge data but all looks fine.

You can find the `.blend` file [here](https://github.com/george-hawkins/blend-bin/blob/master/problem-face-colors.blend?raw=true).

Comment: There are three kinds of normals: vertex, split, and face. Split normals are used for shading. You're looking at face normals. If you want to fix it you can Clear Custom Normal Data under Geometry Data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The normals data is messed up. Here's how to fix it.

[image]

Comment: the "split normals" to be more precise